# Is there a way for me to check 'value-of' value before displaying value in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am beginner to xml/xsl/xslt.

so basically I have this `xsl:value-of select="/root/parent/child/value[@name='actualValue']` which takes value from db

what I am looking for is to check if actualValue has certain char/s before displaying it on dom

```
if(contains(actualValue,'abc')
then(<div>actualValue</div>)
```

logic is something like above if it makes sense?

I saw on some discussions about xsl regarding `xsl:if`, so I tried;

```
<xsl:if test="contains('actualValue','abc')">
<div>Actual Value is </div>
<xsl:value-of select="/root/parent/child/value[@name='actualValue']
</xsl:if>
```

so in the code above, i want the `xsl:if` to see if test is true and then if true, that's the only time that actual value will be displayed on dom

my apologies in advance if the logic is messy, I don't know how xml works. I  am  picturing it as how js usually works. So already big mistake there (^_^)' Please I need help. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="/root/parent/child/value[@name='actualValue']" />
<xsl:if test="contains($myVar, 'abc')">
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="$myVar"/>
    </div>
</xsl:if>
```

I say "probably" because you did not provide a reproducible example we could use for testing.

And we don't know if that's actually the best way to solve the problem; perhaps a better way would be to use an expression like:

```
/root/parent/child/value[@name='actualValue'][contains(., 'abc']
```

Comment: Hi! My apologies for the delayed response. May I know what else I can share because to be honest, I'm not even sure I understand the code itself. I'm not really sure how I can make the logic/my problem code reproducible. Like what else is needed?

Comment: Addendum; actually your last code snippet helped out a lot! It works as expected now. I am really sorry for the way I posited my question as I am really stupid when it comes to new languages(^_^') Thank You Thank You So much!! :)))